# What transformation solves this bit-twiddling pattern?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a series of nibbles (0x0 - 0xF) and a resulting transformation for which a clear pattern results.  The transformation solution simply isn't coming to me (not for a lack of trying).  Is there an experienced bit twiddler out there that recognizes the transformation?  Thanks in advance.

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 0
----------
4 -> 2
5 -> 3
6 -> 3
7 -> 2
----------
8 -> 7
9 -> 6
A -> 6
B -> 7
----------
C -> 5
D -> 4
E -> 4
F -> 5
```

Comment: Looks almost like Gray code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the individual bits it appears that one possible relationship between input and output would be:

```
Y0 = X0^X1^X3
Y1 = X2^X3
Y2 = X3
Y3 = 0
```

where X0..X3 are the input bits and Y0..Y3 are the output bits.

However this requires around 10 or more bitwise operations to implement, so you might be better off just using a lookup table.

Here is a test program in C which verifies that the bitwise logic is correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

static int convert_bitwise(int x)
{
    int x0 = x & 1;
    int x1 = (x & 2) >> 1;
    int x2 = (x & 4) >> 2;
    int x3 = x >> 3;
    int y0 = x0 ^ x1 ^ x3;
    int y1 = x2 ^ x3;
    int y2 = x3;
    return (y2 << 2) | (y1 << 1) | y0;
}

static int convert_lut(int x)
{
    const int LUT[16] = { 0, 1, 1, 0,
                          2, 3, 3, 2,
                          7, 6, 6, 7,
                          5, 4, 4, 5 };
    return LUT[x & 0x0f];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < 16; ++x)
    {
        int y_bitwise = convert_bitwise(x);
        int y_lut = convert_lut(x);

        printf("x = %2d, y (bitwise) = %d, y (LUT) = %d, (%s)\n", x, y_bitwise, y_lut, y_bitwise == y_lut ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall bits4.c && ./a.out 
x =  0, y (bitwise) = 0, y (LUT) = 0, (PASS)
x =  1, y (bitwise) = 1, y (LUT) = 1, (PASS)
x =  2, y (bitwise) = 1, y (LUT) = 1, (PASS)
x =  3, y (bitwise) = 0, y (LUT) = 0, (PASS)
x =  4, y (bitwise) = 2, y (LUT) = 2, (PASS)
x =  5, y (bitwise) = 3, y (LUT) = 3, (PASS)
x =  6, y (bitwise) = 3, y (LUT) = 3, (PASS)
x =  7, y (bitwise) = 2, y (LUT) = 2, (PASS)
x =  8, y (bitwise) = 7, y (LUT) = 7, (PASS)
x =  9, y (bitwise) = 6, y (LUT) = 6, (PASS)
x = 10, y (bitwise) = 6, y (LUT) = 6, (PASS)
x = 11, y (bitwise) = 7, y (LUT) = 7, (PASS)
x = 12, y (bitwise) = 5, y (LUT) = 5, (PASS)
x = 13, y (bitwise) = 4, y (LUT) = 4, (PASS)
x = 14, y (bitwise) = 4, y (LUT) = 4, (PASS)
x = 15, y (bitwise) = 5, y (LUT) = 5, (PASS)
$
```

Comment: Paul, I'm scratching my head looking at your answer and your nomenclature. Take for example `Y0` (for mibble 0x00) are you saying for purposes of your example that would be arrived at by `0^1^11`? Then for `Y0` (for nibble 0x01) would be `1^10^100`? I guess I don't understand what you are calling `X0`, `X1` and `X3`. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin they're just the bits of X. Similarly, Yi is bit i of the result.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was just confused. I am taking the series of nibbles `0x0` - `0xf` to be `0000`, `0001`, `0010` ... `1110`, `1111`. Thanks for your clarification, I'll keep feeling around in the had for the rabbit :)

Comment: Thanks - I've now clarified the terminology and added a test program.

Comment: Paul, Thank you, I am going to consider this question answered, and ask a new question (I realize I over simplified the question and left out constraints on the solution).

Comment: I agree this is the relationship on a bit-level, however it can be implemented with relatively few bitwise operations (not "10 or more bitwise operations") as follows `(n >> 1) ^ (n >> 2) ^ (n >> 3)` where n is a nibble or a nibble-valued-int with zero padding the high bits because XOR is being performed on multiple bits at once.

Comment: @Apriori: unfortunately your expression `(n >> 1) ^ (n >> 2) ^ (n >> 3)` does not give the correct output - I just plugged it into my test harness above and it fails for 8 of the 16 cases. I think you may be on to something though and it's possible that a slightly modified version might give the correct result.

Comment: @Paul R: Ahh good call! The pattern does changes a little in the composition of the lower bit, I lost sight of that somewhere along the way. Here is a way to do it with just one more operation (and I tested it this time): `((n * 0xA0000000) >> 31) ^ (n >> 2) ^ (n >> 1)` It should fold up pretty well on a superscalar. It assumes the nibble is in a 32-bit unsigned int that will roll over and shift in zeros from the right. The multiplication puts the XOR of Y0 and Y2 in the upper bit, placing it in the upper bit saves having to zero (mask) out more bits since you need to shift anyway.

Comment: Cool - that works! I wonder if there's a way to replace the multiply with bitwise operations?

Comment: @Paul R: I like to think of mul as a bitwise shortcut in some cases, especially since it's a pretty fast instruction, at least on x86/64. However I guess it is actually the same number of operations (I haven't counted movs) to do it the bitwise way. `unsigned t = n >> 2; return ((n ^ t) & 1) ^ t ^ (n >> 1);` so one would just have to time it to see which is faster (it could be the lookup table). It's also probably worth noting this problem is perfectly suited for `pshufb`, which can be used to perform a lookup of 16 items at once on a table of 16 bytes, even if you only use one result.

Comment: Yes, multiply is fine on high end CPUs, but a completely bitwise solution is more generally applicable, as multiply can be expensive on low end micro-controllers etc. Good solutions though - well done.